# Dockerfile Gradle Java no such file or directory

Tags: java, docker, gradle, dockerfile

I want create Dockerfile which will create .jar and next step create Docker image.
This application is multi-module Java project. I want build image for each module separately.

3 modules.

```
/Projects/api
├── application
├── model
├── worker
build.gradle
settings.gradle
otherfiles
```

I add deployment catalog which contain Dockerfile

```
/Projects/api
├── application
  ├── deployment
    ├── Dockerfile
```

It is simple Dockerfile

```
FROM gradle:jdk11 as build
COPY --chown=gradle:gradle . /home/gradle/src 
WORKDIR /home/gradle/src
RUN gradle application:jar --no-daemon 

FROM amazoncorretto:11
RUN mkdir /app
COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "/app/app.jar" ]
```

I run `docker build -f application/deployment/Dockerfile -t app:1.0 .`from path `/Project/api` because I think my context is `/Project/api` and I will copy all files. I don't want take care which dependencies is crucial for create .jar for each module separately, so I copy all files.

```
I received error: --                                                                                                                                                                                               
 > [stage-1 3/3] COPY --from=build /home/gradle/src/build/libs/*.jar /app/app.jar:                                                                                                                   
------                                                                                                                                                                                               
lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2641523939/home/gradle/src/build/libs: no such file or directory
```

When I run locally

```
gradle application:jar
```

catalog build/libs was created with expected application*.jar file

What's wrong with Dockerfile or docker build -f command?

Comment: Do you found solution for this?